# Getting error when passing assemble script to build config through Github source code url in OpenShift

Tags: bash, apache, build, openshift, s2i

I am trying to pass assemble script of s2i build image to OpenShift build config (builder image is Apache HTTPD 2.4) from Github repo url(where my web application is present).

But I am getting this error

error: build error: could not download any scripts from URL "https://github.com/some/some.git/some" (sample GitHub URL)